# htaccess code for maintenance page redirect

Tags: htaccess, apache2

I set up a maintenance page that I could enable through an htaccess file. The html file is located in a folder called "maintenance".

The html file has some images in it. However, visitors to the page see no images, even though I added a `RewriteCond` line to (theoretically) allow them.

If I try to visit the URL of an image file in the browser directly, it redirects to the maintenance.htm page. I do not want image files to be redirected.

Am I missing something?

```
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.111.111.111$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/maintenance\.htm$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance/maintenance.htm [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but here is some suggestions for you to try :

1. Put an other .htaccess in the `/maintenance/` folder with a `RewriteEngine Off` to disable the redirection of images once in this folder.
2. Make a sub-domain for your maintenance site and redirect everything to this sub-domain with this temporary redirection in your .htaccess located in your main domain : `Redirect 302 / http://www.maintenance.mydomain.com/` it'll be more logical as a maintenance site is a website inside of an other, and sub-domains are meat to be used for creating different sites inside an other..

Hope it'll work ! :)

Comment: Option 1 works. :) However, why doesn't the `RewriteCond` for images work to begin with?

Comment: Good ! ;) And ohhh after some research I guess I've found the problem, you need to add an "all characters dot" to say that there is stuff before the actual extension... Something like that : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|ico)$ [NC]`